# How can I refresh Query Datatables within an angular 2 project?

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables

I have an Angular project in which I have a table to show data from an array. At first I started up using an angular table but this is renders really slow. I have now added a jQuery datatable (datatables.net) which actually renders pretty fast. Everything seems to work fine(sorting, paging) except for one thing. To refresh the table if the array is changed. I will demonstrate some simple code to show you what I mean.

The table iterate on a simple *ngFor loop on an array of objects:

```
<table id="myTable">
...
<tr *ngFor="let currentRow of currentArray">
...
</table>
```

Let's say this table displays 100 rows. Then I do a server side change of the currentArray which filters it down to 10 rows. Then the usual two-way binding of angular doesn't work anymore. It doesn't update the table. Obviously because it is now a jQuery table. If I print out the currentArray in the console it shows my correct 10 rows.

I was thinking that something like this should work:

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
table.draw()
```

calling this after I filter my array. But no, it doesn't refresh my table. No, it is not an ajax call, just an array of objects being filtered.

Anyone know how I can refresh my jQuery table in my angular 2 solution?

Comment: This is a bad practice in general mixing angular with jQuerry, there is no reason the angular table would not be performant unless you are doing something undesirable for it. A solution to your current question however would be to call change detection manually by importing in your constructor      private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
and then calling on it after your function call for filtering cdr.detectChanges()

Comment: I am quite aware of the bad practice. But if you do a quick google on the matter you will find A lot of people having a hard time with the Angular table and bad performance. It renders too slow. The jQuery on the other hand renders fast. Sooo... back to My question. Yes, I had already tried the ChangeDetectorRef. Doesn't work.

Comment: then put your currentRow in a behavioursubject and subscribe to it with the async pipe in your template. Every time you do a filtering you push the new filtered array to the bsubject.